# Suma de campos dinamicos

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo el siguiente formulario, al momento de ingresar un valor en cantidad y en pu estos se multiplican y me aparece el valor en subtotal, hasta ahi todo bien pero como lo hago pago los mismos campos una segunda vez ya que mi form es dinamico y el usuario puede usar o agregar mas columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que agrega la siguiente fila en caso de dar click en concepto

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 100; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Descripción" value=""/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" id="unidad" name="unidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Unidad">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" id="cantidad2" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" onChange="multiplicar();" placeholder="Cantidad">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" id="pu2" name="pu[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" onChange="multiplicar();" placeholder="P. U.">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">' +
                            '<input type="text" id="subtotal2" name="subtotal[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove_button" title="Remove field"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a><br><br>' +
                    '</div>'; //New input field html
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
```

Y por ultimo con esta otra parte llevo a cabo la multiplicacion que como mencione antes solo se aplica a la primer fila y no si agrego mas, alguien sabe como podria yo solucionarlo

```
<script>
function multiplicar(){
    m1 = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
    m2 = document.getElementById("pu").value;
    r = m1*m2;
    document.getElementById("subtotal").value = r;  
}
```

Comment: Lo más simple sería alcanzar todos los input que registran valores con un mismo elemento (una clase por ejemplo) y asignarles un listener `onchange` en el cual : a) se haga la suma global de todos los elementos de nuevo; o b) se vaya actualizando un objeto con pares (idDelInput : valor) y hacer una suma global de los valores de ese objeto y actualizar el total. Sería una forma organizada de tener en control, más aún sabiendo que el usuario podría cambiar cualquiera de los valores en todo momento. Una opción interesante seria tener atributos data en cada input y guardar ahí los valores.